# SQL query to Outpatient appointments between two Inpatient dates

Tags: sql-server, date

At the moment my report is a prime example of Cartesian product but I can’t seem to find a solution

I have 2 tables, 1 table containing 467 Outpatient appointments and the 2nd contains 62 patients who stayed in overnight (Inpatients). A few patients have 2 or 3 hospital overnight stays and it is these few patients that are causing me a headache

I need to produce a report showing all activity but when a patient has treatment both as an Outpatient and Inpatient, show all the Outpatient appointments between the 2 Inpatient dates

I can’t figure out how to read one row from one table and to read 2 rows form the second table and check 
appoint_date between inpat_date_first and inpat_date_second

The results currently are:-

```
NHS No  IP Start    IP End  OP Appoint  
NHS_No1 21/12/2016  21/12/2016  12/01/2017  1   
NHS_No1 21/12/2016  21/12/2016  16/12/2016  1   
NHS_No1 21/12/2016  21/12/2016  24/11/2016  1   
NHS_No1 21/12/2016  21/12/2016  28/12/2016  1   
NHS_No1 21/12/2016  21/12/2016  06/10/2016  1   
NHS_No1 21/12/2016  21/12/2016  21/07/2016  1   
NHS_No1 21/12/2016  21/12/2016  27/10/2016  1   
NHS_No1 21/12/2016  21/12/2016  08/12/2016  1   
NHS_No1 21/12/2016  21/12/2016  01/12/2016  1   
NHS_No1 21/12/2016  21/12/2016  15/12/2016  1   
NHS_No1 21/12/2016  21/12/2016  21/07/2016  1   
NHS_No1 16/11/2016  16/11/2016  12/01/2017  2   
NHS_No1 16/11/2016  16/11/2016  16/12/2016  2   
NHS_No1 16/11/2016  16/11/2016  24/11/2016  2   
NHS_No1 16/11/2016  16/11/2016  28/12/2016  2                   
NHS_No1 16/11/2016  16/11/2016  06/10/2016  2                   
NHS_No1 16/11/2016  16/11/2016  21/07/2016  2                   
NHS_No1 16/11/2016  16/11/2016  27/10/2016  2                   
NHS_No1 16/11/2016  16/11/2016  08/12/2016  2                   
NHS_No1 16/11/2016  16/11/2016  01/12/2016  2                   
NHS_No1 16/11/2016  16/11/2016  15/12/2016  2                   
NHS_No1 16/11/2016  16/11/2016  21/07/2016  2                   
NHS_No1 31/08/2016  31/08/2016  12/01/2017  3                   
NHS_No1 31/08/2016  31/08/2016  16/12/2016  3                   
NHS_No1 31/08/2016  31/08/2016  24/11/2016  3                   
NHS_No1 31/08/2016  31/08/2016  28/12/2016  3                   
NHS_No1 31/08/2016  31/08/2016  06/10/2016  3                   
NHS_No1 31/08/2016  31/08/2016  06/10/2016  3                   
NHS_No1 31/08/2016  31/08/2016  21/07/2016  3                   
NHS_No1 31/08/2016  31/08/2016  27/10/2016  3                   
NHS_No1 31/08/2016  31/08/2016  27/10/2016  3                   
NHS_No1 31/08/2016  31/08/2016  08/12/2016  3                   
NHS_No1 31/08/2016  31/08/2016  01/12/2016  3                   
NHS_No1 31/08/2016  31/08/2016  15/12/2016  3                   
NHS_No1 31/08/2016  31/08/2016  21/07/2016  3
```

Where as I require:-

```
NHS No  IP Start    IP End  OP Appoint
NHS_No131/08/2016   31/08/2016  21/07/2016
NHS_No1 31/08/2016  31/08/2016  21/07/2016
NHS_No1 31/08/2016  31/08/2016  06/10/2016
NHS_No1 31/08/2016  31/08/2016  06/10/2016
NHS_No1 31/08/2016  31/08/2016  27/10/2016
NHS_No1 31/08/2016  31/08/2016  27/10/2016
NHS_No1 16/11/2016  16/11/2016  24/11/2016
NHS_No1 16/11/2016  16/11/2016  01/12/2016
NHS_No1 16/11/2016  16/11/2016  08/12/2016
NHS_No1 16/11/2016  16/11/2016  15/12/2016
NHS_No1 16/11/2016  16/11/2016  16/12/2016
NHS_No1 21/12/2016  21/12/2016  21/07/2016
NHS_No1 21/12/2016  21/12/2016  28/12/2016
NHS_No1 21/12/2016  21/12/2016  12/01/2017
```

Thanks

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: My efforts to date...
SELECT  IP1.*

       ,OP.*


FROM      [Sandbox].[dbo].[tbl_Wilts_Glaucoma_OPAppoints] OP

LEFT JOIN [Sandbox].[dbo].[tbl_Wilts_Glaucoma_IPSPells]  IP1

ON        IP1.[Pseudonym] = OP.[Pseudonym]

LEFT JOIN [Sandbox].[dbo].[tbl_Wilts_Glaucoma_IPSPells]  IP2

ON        (IP2.[Pseudonym] = OP.[Pseudonym]

AND       OP.[AppointmentDate] BETWEEN IP1.[DischargeDate] AND DATEADD(d, -1, IP2.[DischargeDate]))

Comment: Put what you have tried in the question. The formatting of code in comments is horrible.

Comment: Put the sample data as it is in each input table as well.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am missing something, but why does this not produce the results you are looking for?

```
select ip.*, op.*
from Sandbox.dbo.tbl_Wilts_Glaucoma_ipSpells ip
  inner join Sandbox.dbo.tbl_Wilts_Glaucoma_opAppoints op
    on op.Pseudonym = ip.Pseudonym 
  and op.AppointmentDate >= ip.AdmitDate 
  and op.AppointmentDate <= ip.DischargeDate
```

To show all rows from both tables, but on the same row when op matches the join condition, use a `full outer join`:

```
select ip.*, op.*
from Sandbox.dbo.tbl_Wilts_Glaucoma_ipSpells ip
  full outer join Sandbox.dbo.tbl_Wilts_Glaucoma_opAppoints op
    on op.Pseudonym = ip.Pseudonym 
  and op.AppointmentDate >= ip.AdmitDate 
  and op.AppointmentDate <= ip.DischargeDate
```

Comment: Hi SQLZim
The problem is i need to select all Outpatient appointments whose appointment dates fall between 2 Inpatient spell discharge dates.
i have to compare 1 Outpatient appointment date (1 row) with 2 discharge dates in 2 rows in the Inpatients table
I'm sorry to everyone for my lack of clarity - it's sometimes hard to step back and explain the issue to others in a clear and meaningful manner

Answer (score 0):

Sussed it. 
Thanks to those of you who helped clear the cobwebs for a solution to be found